# How do I get rid of the ugly lines around my object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am creating an inflatable pink flamingo in Cycles, and there is an ugly black line at the edge of my mesh that I don't know how to get rid of. Here are my materials and a sample render. How do I get rid of the black lines at the edge of my mesh? [image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe your lighting, how does it look in solid shading? Have you checked for any overlapping geometry?

Comment: @corgijumper, maybe you could be so kind as to upload a copy of your ~.blend file to [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), and edit the link to the file into your quesiton.

Comment: This can be a bad alignement of the vertices around the x-axis (bad clipping or no clipping in the mirror modifier)

Comment: Upload your file please

Answer (score 1):

First, it is hard to tell without your .blend file, but I believe I have a two part solution.

### Part 1

Many of your nodes are repetitive and unnecessary. You would get a near-identical result with just the following. Use the *Layer Weight* node's slider to affect the glossiness (**higher value = more glossiness**).

[image]

*Original node setup vs. My node setup:*

[image] vs. [image]

### Part 2

I assume you have *Smooth Shading* on, as activated in the *Toolshelf*. If you do, either return to *Flat Shading* or add a *Subdivision surface* object modifier.

To add such a modifier, first go to the *Object Modifiers* tab in the *Properties panel*. Select *Subdivision surface* from the options. Set both the *View:* value to 2 and the *Render:* value to 3.

*Final modifier settings:*

[image]

*Smooth shaded Suzanne without any subsurf:*

[image]

*Smooth shaded Suzanne with subsurf at 3:*

[image]

*Flat shaded Suzanne:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix the lines around my mesh this way!

Comment: @corgijumper If you liked my answer, please consider accepting it.